# how to sql works: select months_between ('29-Mar-2015' ,'28-Feb-2015') as m from dual;

Tags: sql, oracle

Months_between function does not work properly: from March to February:

```
select months_between('28-Mar-2015','28-Feb-2015') as months from dual; => 1    Correct=0.90  
select months_between('29-Mar-2015','28-Feb-2015') as months from dual; => 1.03 Correct=0.94    
select months_between('30-Mar-2015','28-Feb-2015') as months from dual; => 1.06 Correct=0.97    
select months_between('31-Mar-2015','28-Feb-2015') as months from dual; => 1    Correct=1
```

The above oracle sql give me such results. Such as: Question1 answer = 1; Question2 answer = 1.03; Question3 answer = 1.06; Question4 answer = 1; We know that last date to last date is 1 month. How it possible last date to 29th or 30th date means grater than 1 ?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Actually i want to know that '28/Mar/15' - '28/Feb/15'=28 days. 28 day =0.90 month but sql shows 1.03 month that is not correct; '29/Mar/15' - '28/Feb/15'=29 days. 29 days= 0.94 month but sql shows 1.03 month that is not correct. '30/Mar/15' - '28/Feb/15'=30 days. 30 days=0.97 month but sql shows 1.06 month that is not correct. Because 28 February is the last day of February and 31 March is the last day of March. So, 31/Mar/15-28/Feb/15=31 days = 1 month is correct. 
How to get 
28/Mar/15-28/Feb/15=0.90 month
29/Mar/15-28/Feb/15=0.94 month  and
30/Mar/15-28/Feb/15=0.97 month.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

to quote the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm):

> MONTHS_BETWEEN returns number of months between dates date1 and date2.
>   If date1 is later than date2, then the result is positive. If date1 is
>   earlier than date2, then the result is negative. If date1 and date2
>   are either the same days of the month or both last days of months,
>   then the result is always an integer. Otherwise Oracle Database
>   calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day
>   month and considers the difference in time components date1 and date2.

So on example 1, there are 31 days in between both dates, so the result is 1.
On example 2, date 1 is later then date 2, so the result is positive, and because its one day more then a full month, the result is 1.03
The same thing happens with example 3, but now there are 2 days more then a full month of time difference, so the result is 1.06
On the last example we have two dates that are the last dates of those months, so the result is again 1.

In short, the function works as it was designed, but it might not suit your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want values like in your example then you can substract dates and divide them by 31:

```
select round((date '2015-03-28' - date '2015-02-28') / 31, 2) from dual;    -- 0.90
select round((date '2015-03-29' - date '2015-02-28') / 31, 2) from dual;    -- 0.94
select round((date '2015-03-30' - date '2015-02-28') / 31, 2) from dual;    -- 0.97
select round((date '2015-03-31' - date '2015-02-28') / 31, 2) from dual;    -- 1
```

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) average number of days in year
is 365.2425, so maybe instead of 31 you will want to divide by (365.2425/12) - approximately 30,436875.

---

Why Oracle gives such results?

For dates 29-Mar and 28-Feb days are different (29, 28) and not both are last days of month so Oracle calculates this way: 1 + (29-28)/31.